# Selenium Web Driver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to identify a "search" in Kayak.co.in/flights/One-way page in selenium web driver.

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.kayak.co.in/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/flights']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@title = 'One-way']")).click();  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id='-submit')]")).click();
    driver.quit();
```

Getting the following exception after executing the above code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id='-
submit')]"}
```

Comment: Xpath //*[contains(@id='-submit')] should be written as //*[contains(@id,'-submit')]. Replace '=' with ',' when using contains function to identify elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple buttons with this xpath. You should specify more your xpath to obtain an unique button. Try with this one `.//div[contains(@class,'Flights-Search-StyleJamFlightSearchForm')]/.//div[contains(@class,'centre')]/button[@title='Search']`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a WebElement while calling an element to precisely targeting it and using moveToElement command instead of simply calling FindElement.By.xxxxx ex:

```
//*** Calling a WebElement and using moveToElement command***//

WebElement (anyElementname) = browser.findElement(By.partialLinkText("xxxxxxxxxxx"));
          action.moveToElement(anyElementname).perform();
//*** Waiting for 8 seconds***//          
Thread.sleep(8000, 80000);
```

You can use 'waits' for providing page load time and interacting between elements

I am converting first xpath (flights) command for you. You can do the rest in the same way:

```
WebElement flights = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/flights']")).click();
action.moveToElement(flights).perform();
```

Dont forget to import relevant libraries like for action, you have to import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Let me know if it works for you or not. Cheers!